# Information leakage due to fault propagation in XOR gates

Tags: logic-gates, testing, fault

From the paper [Fault Template Attacks on Block Ciphers Exploiting Fault Propagation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/937), in the concept of Automatic Test Pattern Generation (ATPG), two events are required to perform in sequence: **Fault Activation** and **Fault Propagation**.

[image]

In the case of a linear 2-input XOR gate,

> without loss of generality, we consider a stuck-at-0 fault at the
> input register *a*, while the input register *b* may take values
> independently. In order to activate the fault at *a*, one must set *a*
> = 1. The next step is to propagate the fault at the output. One may observe that setting the input *b* to either 0 or 1 will expose the
> fault at *a* to the output *o*.

and comes to the following conclusion:

> *Given an n-input XOR gate having an input set I, (|I| = n), an output*
> *O, and a faulted input $i \in I$, the fault propagation to O does*
> *not depend upon the valuations of the subset I \ {i}.*

Moreover, in continuation of article, he says

> with assuming the fault to be stuck-at-0, just by observing whether
> the output is faulty, Adversary can determine the value of *a*. More
> precisely, if the output is fault-free *a* = 0 and *a* = 1, otherwise.

I am confused at this point. When the type of fault is stuck-at-0, how can the value of *a* be equal to 0 in the case of "fault-free"? Have I misunderstood the concept? I think when we perform stuck-at-0 fault attack, the value of *a* is equal to 0 and if we know the output is faulty, we can just say that the output is equal to the value of *b*. Can anyone tell me what is the use of this method? I am confused!

Comment: One wonders if a *stuck-at-0* fault is a likely fault condition. What about disconnected inputs? To what logic state do they float to?

Comment: Probably because of their use in the primitives of cryptography (S-Boxes), they will never be left float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to activate the fault at a, one must **set** a = 1.

The fault condition is that `a` stays stuck at at 0 even when **set** to 1 (ie. when the signal connected to it is trying to make it 1). So if it is set to 1 *and becomes* 1 at/in the gate then the output will be good, whereas if it is set to 1 but stays at 0 then the output will be bad. If it is set to 0 then the output will always be good whether it is stuck or not.

So by observing whether the output is good or bad, and *knowing* that `a` is stuck at 0, if the output is bad then you know that the input to `a` was set to 1, whereas if the output is good you know that the input to `a` was set to 0. Thus information about the signal input to `a` has leaked through.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with this problem dear @BruceAbbott. You described it best. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

> how can the value of a be equal to 0 in the case of "fault-free"?

Here, somehow, faulty means `o=~b`, whereas fault-free means `o=b`. I have no idea why the author chose such a meaning of the terms "faulty" and "fault-free". The resource you're presumably citing tries to use fancy language - perhaps to hide author's shaky understanding? It's an annoyingly roundabout way of describing simple stuff :(

Comment: Exactly! He has expressed a simple stuff in a bad language. Thank you for your guidance. Merry Christmas.